# Select All? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get this Select All code to work but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I found the code here
http://jsfiddle.net/L6e72fpv/

I'm not sure if it's a compatibility issue or if I'm putting the code together wrong.  It works fine on the jsfiddle but not on an full page.
Here is the way I have it in a page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;" charset="utf-8" />
<title>TEST</title>
<script>
$("#checkAll").change(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#">
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" /> Check all</label>
  </p>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Loads of checkboxes</legend>
    <p>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" /> Option 1</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" /> Option 2</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" /> Option 3</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" /> Option 4</label>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put your script at the bottom, Your are trying to assign the event before the checkboxes are actually created. To make it work at the top, put it in a document.ready function and jquery neeeds to be included

Comment: Did you import jQuery to your full page? Are you sure you don't have more elements with the id `checkAll` in your full page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your'e not including the jQuery Library. Without loading it, jQuery won't work. You also closed your body and html tag twice.

Try this:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;" charset="utf-8" />
<title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#">
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" /> Check all</label>
  </p>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Loads of checkboxes</legend>
    <p>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" /> Option 1</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" /> Option 2</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" /> Option 3</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" /> Option 4</label>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#checkAll").change(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I've done is include jQuery
`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>`
and added your script after loading it. It works fine now!

Comment: Thank you. I'm still new to JQuery.  The extra /html and /body got left behind from deleting code.  Didn't realized I missed them.